# Html.Action ignoring namespace from original controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, controller, namespaces

i have the following problem:
in my MVC project i have more controller with the same name but different namespaces

- Web.Controllers.HomeController
- Web.Controllers.CustomerController
- Admin.Controllers.HomeController
- Admin.Controllers.CustomerController

My only route so far is:

```
var DefaultRoute = routes.MapLocalizedRoute("default",
                            "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
          new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
                      new[] {"Admin.Controllers"});
DefaultRoute.DataTokens["UseNamespaceFallback"] = true;
```

With a default fallback of:

```
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Clear();
ControllerBuilder.Current.DefaultNamespaces.Add("Web.Controllers");
```

With the intention of trying to take always the controller of namespace Admin and if the controller is not yet implemented but is in namespace Web then take this.
Which works, but the problem comes in

```
@HTML.Action("Login","Customer");
```

which apparently always takes Web.Controllers disregarding the namespace of the original controller.

Can i somehow make that work?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By looking at your problem it looks like web controller is the main controller (shared) and admin controller is within an area.

To take `Html.Action` to the controller within the area you need to explicitly specify the area name

like `@Html.Action("Login", "Customer", new { area = "Admin" })`.

Comment: Thank you.  Because of this I discovered that you can also add:  new {area = "" } in order to specify the route go to an area-less controller that has the same name.